# differences in IF statement style in VHDL

Tags: if-statement, vhdl

what is best between these two IF statement implementation:

```
IF ( A and B) THEN
  ...
ELSIF ( A ) THEN -- implying B is zero
  ...
END IF;
```

and this

```
IF ( A ) THEN
  IF ( B ) THEN
    ...
  ELSE
    ...
  END IF;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Since you are asking for opinions your question should be closed. But to give at least something to think about:*

Well, it depends. If your `A` and `B` are such that the first version makes more sense than the second version, use the first. If it is the other way around, use the second.

I'm sure that both versions are synthesizes to the same gate level logic.